# Transparent image - background color

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if it is possible to set a background color for transparent images? (only the image will have background color)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If I understand you right, you can do this:

```
<img src="image.png" style="background-color:red;" />
```

In fact, you can even apply a whole `background-image` to the image, resulting in two "layers" without the need for multi-background support in the browser ;)

Comment: Is there a resource to show how widely supported this usage of `background-color` is?

Comment: @TylerForsythe Erm... well I could give you a list of browsers. Every browser supports this.

Comment: Hi @NiettheDarkAbsol, "all of them" is sufficient. Thanks!